# htaccess: Remove second part of url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently i have 100+ URLs on my site in this format:

http://www.example.in/view_retailer/homepage

I want to remove **/view_retailer/** from all URLs, so they should look something like this

http://www.example.in/homepage

In other words I would to always remove **/view_retailer/** from the url. I'm sure it's really straight forward, but I'm not very experienced with .htaccess

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^view_retailer/(.*)$ $1
```

This is my current htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    <FilesMatch "\.inc.php">
      order deny,allow
      deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

     Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php            
        RewriteRule ^view_retailer/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view_retailer/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Adding the R will change the url to appear like the new version in your address bar

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable response, but I am not able to achieve it

Comment: According to http://htaccess.mwl.be/ it will work perfectly, make sure you don't have another rewrite rule with "L" as an option.

Also, please reply with what is going wrong, not just that it doesn't work. If you post your entire htaccess file, that would help understand if there is a problem.

Comment: @Asperon: I have edited my answer. I have posted htaccess file. I am getting page not found error.

Comment: Ok, maybe put it as the first rule, instead of the last. At the very least put it above these lines 

RewriteRule view_retailer/(.*)/desc/(.*)/ view_retailer.php?id=$1&desc=$2 [L]

Comment: @Asperon: I have added it above view_retailer/(.*)/desc/(.*)/ view_retailer.php?id=$1&desc=$2 [L]. But I am getting same error, I have flushed my browser's cache also now

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, appears to be working, according to http://htaccess.mwl.be/ it meets the rewrite and processes it. If you are getting a 404, it may be the URL you are testing with, can you send me the URL you are trying to hit?

Comment: @Asperon: You are right, it is working in htaccess.mwl.be . This is the url http://www.dev.whitecashback.in/view_retailer/ebay-in   . I am getting this error NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.dev.whitecashback.in/ebay-in

Comment: Remove your request filename conditions. The -f one definately breaks things. Not sure about the directory check.